# Load Multi-page .tif files into PDF using Zend Framework

Tags: pdf, tiff, zend-pdf

I am able to successfully load a single page .tif image into a PDF using ZendFramework, here is the code:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_LETTER);
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('/tmp/test.tif');
$pageHeight = $page->getHeight();
$pageWidth = $page->getWidth();
$page->drawImage($image, 0, 0, $pageWidth, $pageHeight);
$pdf->pages[] = page;
```

I have multi-page .tif files, is there a way to load multi-page files into a single PDF using only the ZendFramework library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on linux, you could move the tiff into a temp folder, use [tiffsplit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tiffsplit) to split it into single page tiffs with shell_exec, run them through a loop to add each consecutive tiff to a new pdf page, then delete the temp data.